# want to prevent replacement in command mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, text-editor

I download a .vimrc file from the web, everything works well but I found that the file allows vim editor to have permission to replace/delete selected word in command mode. for example, i want to select some lines and use 'y' to yank those lines, then it suddenly converted into insert mode and replace those selected lines to 'y', cut function works as well ( leave 'd'). I don't know which lines of .vimrc file, or which keyword in .vimrc file make vim to do these.

Comment: it is a good example to show why it is a bad practice to use someone else's vim config without understanding.  You should check when the `y` was mapped. what does `:verbose map y` tell u?

Comment: I can't find out  :verbose map y .  and not only 'y' but everything. (command mode) If i select a block and input anything, the block will be substituted by those inputted (also including 'deleting') and automatically switched to inserting mode

Comment: then do a binary-search to locate the problem

Comment: @Kent was asking the output of `:verbose map y` when you run it from vim. I doubt if you confused that with searching for the same in `.vimrc` could you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understood what Kent means by those command, but you should know that it is not the problem only related with 'y'. Finally I figure out what the problem was. with my mouse available in vim, when I select those lines with my mouse, I found that the mode changed from command mode to SELECT mode which is different from Visual Mode.
After all, Thanks for all  !!